# Contact form is changing order of form data

Tags: arrays, perl, cgi

I have a contact form that uses a CGI script to get form data and send through email. The script works fine except for the fact that it seems to change the order of form elements. I think I have pinpointed the block of code responsible for this.

Is there a way to alter this so that it sends the form data as-is, without re-ordering?

```
sub get_data {

    use CGI qw/:standard/;
    my $query = new CGI;
    foreach $key ($query->param()){    
        $data{$key} = $query->param($key);
    }
    %data;      # return associative array of name=value
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`perldoc CGI`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Elds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI.pm#FETCHING_THE_NAMES_OF_ALL_THE_PARAMETERS_PASSED_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT:)

> If the script was invoked with a parameter list (e.g. "name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3"), the param() method will return the parameter names as a list. If the script was invoked as an  script and contains a string without ampersands (e.g. "value1+value2+value3") , there will be a single parameter named "keywords" containing the "+"-delimited keywords.
>
> NOTE: As of version 1.5, the array of parameter names returned will be in the same order as they were submitted by the browser. Usually this order is the same as the order in which the parameters are defined in the form (however, this isn't part of the spec, and so isn't guaranteed).

So you can keep order of keys by storing them in array,

```
my @ordered = $query->param();
```

or don't use hash at all,

```
my @data;
foreach $key ($query->param()){    
    push @data, [ $key, $query->param($key) ];
}
return @data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're putting your parameters into a hash. And hashes have no intrinsic ordering. The only way to get key/value pairs out for a hash in the same order as you put them in, is to keep a separate array containing the order of the keys.

Do you really need the parameters in a hash? Can't you just use your `foreach` loop at the point when you're creating the email?